# Python Git and Git-Lab create project and push code/commit

Tags: python-3.x, python-gitlab

We are building an automation process using python in which we clone a base source code repository and add necessary changes to it and add the new code to a new git repository and push it to our private gitlab server.

So far I'm using git library to clone, and initial a new repository and make an initial commit. however I'm not able to figure out "how to create and push the new repository to our private gitlab server.

```
import gitlab
import git
import json
import shutil
"""GitLab API"""
gl = gitlab.Gitlab('gitlab url of company', private_token='the token', api_version=4)
gl.auth()

"""Cloning the Base Code"""
git.Repo.clone_from("url","path to save")


"""Getting data"""
data_json = getData()

""" Copy Base Code to New Folder with Doctor Name"""
repo_name = "new_repo"

shutil.copytree("./base_code/public", "{}/public".format(repo_name))
shutil.copytree("./base_code/src", "{}/src".format(repo_name),dirs_exist_ok=True)
shutil.copy("./base_code/.gitignore", "{}/".format(repo_name))
shutil.copy("./base_code/package-lock.json", "{}/".format(repo_name))
shutil.copy("./base_code/package.json", "{}/".format(repo_name))
shutil.copy("./base_code/README.md", "{}/".format(repo_name))

"""Generate JSON File and save it new folder"""

with open("./{}/src/data.json".format(repo_name), 'w') as fout:
    json_dumps_str = json.dumps(data_json, indent=4)
    print(json_dumps_str, file=fout)

"""Create new git repo in the new folder"""
new_repo = git.Repo.init('{}'.format(repo_name))

"""Adding all the files to Staged Scenario"""    
new_repo.index.add(['.'])

"""Commit the changes"""
new_repo.index.commit('Initial commit.')

"""Create Project of the new Repository"""
```

> How to create project and push the code to the new project?

Comment: On most hosting servers, "create new project" has to be done directly on that hosting server, using their web interface or API(s). So, look for GitLab's API documentation for how-to-create-repository. Once you've figured that part out, look at the git-python documentation to see how to hook up a newly created repository with some other repository by adding a "remote".

Comment: @torek im looking for the gitlab api. but unable to find it.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=gitlab+api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I created a new project in gitlab in python using python-gitlab libary.

```
gl = gitlab.Gitlab('gitlab website url', private_token='token', api_version=4)
gl.auth()
gl.projects.list()

"""Create Project of the new Repository"""
response = gl.projects.create({"name":"project name","namespace_id":"group-id if required"})
```

> The documentation of python-gitlab doesnt have any direct sample code
> for this use-case.